# db2 query top group by

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, highest

I've been trying for hours but can't ge the query, i want to do the following using DB2. From table Company and Users I have the following tickets quantity info per company/user

```
QUERY USING:
SELECT T.USER, COUNT(T.USER) AS QUANITTY, T.COMPANY FROM TICKET T
INNER JOIN COMPANY P ON P.COMPANY = T.COMPANY
GROUP BY (T.USER, T.COMPANY) ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC
```

Outcome is:

```
user         company      quantity
----------------------------------
mark         nissn        300
tom          toyt         50
steve        kryr         80
mark         frd          20    
tom          toyt         120    
jose         toyt         230    
tom          nissn        145    
steve        toyt         10    
jose         kryr         35    
steve        frd          100
```

THIS SHOULD BE THE RESULT(Top user per company)

```
user         company      quantity
----------------------------------
mark         nissn        300    
jose         toyt         230    
steve        frd          100    
steve        kryr         80
```

as you can see there are many users in a company and each have different quantities per company, the result should
get the user with the highest quantity per company. i.e. : Company `nissn` it has 2 users and each has (mark with 300) and (tom with 145)

so it should give me the highest user which would be mark with 300. The same would be for `toyt`, `frd`, `kryr`. I need all of them in a query.
I wonder if that's possible in a query or I will need to create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [analytic queries](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-analytic-topn.html).  But be careful.  The pattern usually works out to involve nested subqueries.  (One to produce a dataset, the next to add it to the pattern, the third to select out the rows you want.)

In this case it should look something like this.

Original query.

```
SELECT T.USER, COUNT(T.USER) AS QUANTITY, T.COMPANY
FROM TICKET T
  JOIN COMPANY P
    ON P.COMPANY = T.COMPANY
GROUP BY (T.USER, T.COMPANY)
```

Analytic query.  (Note that the `s` is to name the subquery.  I have not used DB2, but the standard strictly doesn't prevent them to be dropped, and I know at least one database that requires them.)

```
SELECT user, quantity, company
  , RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY quantity DESC) as r
FROM ( ... previous query ... ) s
```

Final result.

```
SELECT user, quantity, company
FROM ( ... previous query ... ) t
WHERE r = 1
```

The combined query is:

```
SELECT user, quantity, company
FROM (
    SELECT user, quantity, company
      , RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY quantity DESC) as r
    FROM (
        SELECT T.USER, COUNT(T.USER) AS QUANTITY, T.COMPANY
            FROM TICKET T
              JOIN COMPANY P
                ON P.COMPANY = T.COMPANY
            GROUP BY (T.USER, T.COMPANY)
      ) s
  ) t
WHERE r = 1
```

As I say I have not used DB2.  But according to the SQL standard, that query should work.

Comment: you gave me the right answear and yes it also works perfect for DB2 !!! I'be been trying to do this but couldnt figure out. Thank you bubby!

Comment: Also, consider using Dense_Rank() instead of Rank() to manage a tie between two companies.  Great job breaking it down into step-by-step instructions @btilly